# Java Dynamic Matrix

Tags: java, editor, maze

OK so the title tells little, but I am looking to make an editor of sorts for mazes. I had an assignment to make a maze solver. I did this by reading a file. The first line has the row and column count. After that it is a maze of symbols to make the maze. I ran through each place and depending on the symbol made a matrix with a number representing what was there.

```
For Instance:

11 25
*************************
*  ***                 **
**   * ***** *****   ****
** ***  **********   ****
** ****      *       ****
**     ***** *****     **
** *** ***** ********* **
** *** ***** ********* **
**  ** ***** ********* **
*  ***         ***     **
*****************   *****

1111111111111111111111111
1001110000000000000000011
1100010111110111110001111
1101110011111111110001111
1101111000000100000001111
1100000111110111110000011
1101110111110111111111011
1101110111110111111111011
1100110111110111111111011
1001110000000001110000011
1111111111111111100011111
```

That is my matrix that comes out. Now I have this solving this, so that isn't an issue. But I want it so I can ask the row count and column count, draw a rectangle that size, make a matrix [row][column] big with all 0's, that fits in the screen, grid it based on the matrix and then when they click the box that is for matrix[0][0] it changes that to a 1 and so one for each grid box that represents a spot in the matrix.

That way I can allow them to make a maze and then have the program solve it, or they can save it.

Of course this is where I am having issues, how do I draw a rectangle that has a grid based on the count of rows and columns then make it so I know where they clicked......

Any help would be great.

EDIT: OK I have it drawing the maze based on rows and columns given. I have it detecting the click and it can put on square where I click. But it isn't changing the overall matrix and then redraw the whole thing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to have already worked out, you can make a maze of any particular size using the `new` operator:

```
int[][] maze = new int[rows][cols];
```

I don't know what user interface package you are using, but most work along the same lines: the screen is a certain number of pixels wide and high, and you draw lines by specifying the pixel coordinates of the start and end. Likewise, when a user clicks, you get the click coordinates in pixels. You can determine the size of your boxes by taking the overall width and height of the screen and dividing by the number of rows and columns of your maze. Use those dimensions to draw the maze. You can also determine the row and column of a click by taking the (x,y) coordinates of the click in pixels and dividing x by the box width and y by the box height (possibly after adjusting for where you started drawing the maze, if it wasn't at pixel (0,0)).

Comment: hmm I tried something like that, but I still cant seem to make it work. The size of the window is set at 500,500 to start, the maze is drawn starting at 0,0 and then over column amounts and down row amounts. With boxes of size windowWidth/columns and windowHieght/rows.

Comment: What's not working? You may have to adjust the formula slightly to account for the width of the box boundaries.